# NHibernate create object using custom factory

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle

I need help with nHibernate. My project requires using my custom Factory to create model classes instead of useing constructors. But I don't know how I can force on nHibernate using factory. I found [article](http://kozmic.net/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/) which describe nhibernate without default constructor, but It doesn't compile, because in class CustomProxyFactory, we call SetInterceptors with LazyInitializer and LazyFieldInterceptor arguments, which doesn't implement IInterceptor interface.

I use nHibernate 3.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at autofac nhibernate integration as a good example:

https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/tree/master/Extras/Source/Autofac.Extras.NHibernate/Bytecode

You will then have to set your optimizer to nhibernate as in:

```
    NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BytecodeProvider = new AutofacBytecodeProvider(GetLifetimeScope, new DefaultProxyFactoryFactory(), new DefaultCollectionTypeFactory());
```

Comment: This require .net 4.0, but I can use max 3.5

Comment: "This" refers to ? If you mean autofac, that's not what you should use. I just gave it to you as an example to see how to customize object creation. You don't need autofac. Though You can roll your own implementation by looking at that code